# Change Icon color in a TimestampedGeoJson

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, folium

I am trying to make a map including popups with iframes markers with different colors and icons with the data included in a geojson . I have no problem with the popups, but I can't change the icon colors.

I have tried the following ways and other ones that I can't remember to introduce the color in 'properties' without any result:

```
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'icon': {'color': 'red'},...}

{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'color': 'red',...}

{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'style': {'color': 'red'},...}

{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'icon': 'marker', 'color': 'red',...}
```

Here is my code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson

m=folium.Map(location=[46, 20.00],
  zoom_start=7,
  tiles="stamenterrain")

features = [{'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'color': 'green',
   'name': 'Photo 1',
   'time': '2012-01-01',
   'popup': "<iframe src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/96491/pexels-photo-96491.jpeg title='test' width='200' height='100'/>"},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [19.295, 46.5116]}},
 {'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'color': 'red',
   'name': 'Photo 2',
   'time': '2012-04-01',
   'popup': "<iframe src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/1145370/pexels-photo-1145370.jpeg title='test' width='200' height='100'/>"},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [18.15291, 47.20544]}}]


TimestampedGeoJson(
    {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features},
    period='P3M',
    duration='P2M',
    auto_play=False,
    add_last_point=True,
    min_speed=0.5,
    max_speed=2,
    loop=False,
    loop_button=True,
    date_options='YYYY/MM/DD',
).add_to(m)

m
```

I expect to obtain a map with green and red colors, but markers are showed in blue.

If I use circle icon using `'properties': {'icon': 'circle', 'iconstyle': {'color': 'green'}` the circles are created with teh correct color.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `color` with `iconColor` like this:

`'properties': {'icon': 'circle', 'iconstyle': {'iconColor': 'green'}`