# Using a custom icon in timestampedgeojson

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am trying to use a png as an icon on a timestampedgeojson map, but have been unable to make it work. I think I am using the wrong property name but am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
Feature(
                geometry = Point((longitude, latitude)),
                properties = {
                    
                    'popup': i[1],
                    'time': i[5],
                    'icon': 'icon.png'
                                            
                }
```

This is my first stack overflow post, so please let me know if I did not explain well.

Comment: Here is an example of an [official custom icon](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/CustomIcon.ipynb) for your reference.

Comment: @r-beginners I am trying to use timestampedgeojson. The link you posted seems to be referencing folium.

Comment: I was mistaken. Please refer to [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Plugins.ipynb). There was also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519971/change-icon-color-in-a-timestampedgeojson).

Comment: The first link worked for me. Thank you for your answer!